# como aplicar BufferedInputStream StringBuilder con un archivo txt en java

Tags: java

Necesito abrir un archivo y cortar un segmento del texto (en forma de `array`). Digo cortar porque quiero que se elimine del archivo.

Hice algo parecido con unas `url`, y quisiera saber cómo sería con un archivo. y si es recomendable el mismo método. Éste es el código:

```
URL url = new url("http:www.web.com";
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

BufferedInputStream buffer = new 
BufferedInputStream(urlc.getInputStream());

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int byteRead;
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
    builder.append((char) byteRead);
}

buffer.close();
String urldescargada = "";
urldescargada = (builder.toString());
```

Una vez hecho eso ya puedo trabajar, con `indexOf` y `split` logro separar lo que necesito. Lo que no sé es cómo hacerlo en un archivo y que elimine lo que extraje.

Comment: ¿Es un fichero de texto? ¿Cómo está definido? Edita con un ejemplo del contenido de ese fichero. Para leerlo, si es texto plano, no debes utilizar `BufferedInputStream` sino `FileReader` y `BufferedReader`. Si aportas este tipo de datos, la ayuda vendrá rápidamente. Si no... complicado.

Comment: El archivo que trato de modificar es el html que se guarda al descargar una pagina web. Es lo mismo que leo cuando me conecto al url, solo que ya lo tengo descargado en un archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para cortar información en un archivo es necesario leerlo, guardar lo que necesites en una variable (el contenido a cortar) y lo que queres que esté en el archivo en otra (el resto del archivo). Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
File file = new File("archivo.txt");
BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));        
StringBuilder builderCortado = new StringBuilder();     //string que queres guardar
StringBuilder builderNoCortado = new StringBuilder();   //resto del archivo
boolean cortar = true;
int byteRead;
while ((byteRead = buffer.read()) != -1) {
    if(byteRead == '\n') {      //deja de cortar al detectar un salto de linea
        cortar = false;
        continue;               //para que el salto de linea no esté en el string final
    }
    if(cortar == true) {
        builderCortado.append((char) byteRead);
    }else {
        builderNoCortado.append((char) byteRead);
    }
}
buffer.close(); 
//escribis el resto del archivo
FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);  
out.write(builderNoCortado.toString());
out.close();
String urldescargada = "";
urldescargada = (builderCortado.toString());
```

Espero que te sirva